# Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh

Can someone explain in simple english which of the two following definitions fit that error message:

1. The server is expecting public private key authentication but my machine is giving an incorrect key
2. The server is expecting public private key authentication but my machine is not giving any key at all
3. My machine is giving a key but the server is not expecting a key

Comment: could you develop a bit more what are you trying to do or what are the steps that end up giving this error?

Comment: This reads more like homework or study-assignment to me.  How it relates to your Ubuntu system, your error message & how we can help you with Ubuntu would help us to help you.